# Jquery Ajax autocomplete, Calling function on ajax success and call autocomplete on Json object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I call a function from document.ready which makes an ajax call. If the ajax call receives a response successfully, then the callback function is called in it. In callback function, I'm writing the autocomplete on the json object array. But the autocomplete event is not firing for some reason.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        getTheSearchDataForAutoComplete();
    });


function getTheSearchDataForAutoComplete(){



$.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: 'url',


        contentType: "application/json",
        data: formToJSONGetDoctorIdAndRole(),
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR){ 

                //The callback function in which using the autocomplet
                callback(response.payload)



        },
        error: function(err){
            alert('ERROR IN getTheSearchDataForAutoComplete ' + err.status);

        }
    });
```

}

Given below is the callback function, but in the callback function autocomplete event is not getting fired.

```
 function callback(result){

    //var prescriptionDataForSearch = result;


 //It is the raw to test
 var data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Will",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "created_at": "2015-01-27T13:09:20.243Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-01-27T13:09:20.243Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Willem",
        "last_name": "Dafoe",
        "created_at": "2015-01-27T13:17:23.479Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-01-27T13:17:23.479Z"
    }
];

     $('#add-symptom-textbox').autocomplete({

        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {


           var array = $.map (data, function (value, key) {

                return {
                    label: value.first_name,
                    //value: value.first_name
                }
            });

            //Filter the data locally
             response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));

        }

    });  

}
```

But when I call that function from the document.ready. It is working.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       callback();
    });
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also, are you getting a successful response or not?

Comment: no, I am not getting any error